# How to change background color of the popup error message in textinputlayout

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

I want to change the background color of the popup error message of a `TextInputLayout`. More precisely:

[image]

I want to know how to change the black and the red/pink color of the popup box that contain my error's message.

Comment: It's not duplicate because all the answers were for changing the text color and i want to change the background color of the popup

Comment: It is a duplicate. If you would read the whole thing, you would know that this can't be easily done and also not all the answers are about changing the text color.